# Aligning multiple lines in long equations and arranging the line breaks in `\align` environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, vertical-alignment, line-breaking, align

I have the following code sample:

```
\begin{align}
    \pi^{(1)}_{i j} \enspace & = \enspace -\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\lambda \sigma} \left( \eta^{\mu \alpha}\eta^{\nu \beta} + \eta^{\mu \beta}\eta^{\nu \alpha}  \right) \biggl\{ \frac{1}{2}\delta_{\lambda 0}( \delta_{\mu i}\delta_{\nu j} + \delta_{\mu j}\delta_{\nu i}  )   \biggr\} \partial_{\sigma} h_{\alpha \beta}
    \nonumber
    \\
    -\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\lambda \sigma} \left( \eta^{\mu \alpha}\eta^{\nu \beta} + \eta^{\mu \beta}\eta^{\nu \alpha}  \right) \biggl\{ \frac{1}{2}\delta_{\sigma 0}( \delta_{\alpha i}\delta_{\beta j} + \delta_{\alpha j}\delta_{\beta i} )  \biggr\} \partial_{\lambda} h_{\mu \nu}
    \mspace{-458mu}
    \nonumber
    \\
    & = \enspace -\frac{1}{4}\partial^{\lambda} h^{\mu \nu}\delta_{\lambda 0}( \delta_{\mu i}\delta_{\nu j} + \delta_{\mu j}\delta_{\nu i} ) -\frac{1}{4}\partial^{\sigma} h^{\alpha \beta}\delta_{\sigma 0}( \delta_{\alpha i}\delta_{\beta j} + \delta_{\alpha j}\delta_{\beta i} )
    \nonumber
    \\
    & = \enspace -\frac{1}{2}\partial^0 h^{i j} - \frac{1}{2}\partial^0 h^{i j}
    \nonumber
    \\
    & = \enspace \dot{h}_{i j}
\end{align}
```

which gives the output:

[image: output of the given code]

As you see, I have a problem in aligning the lines properly which I tried to handle by using `\mspace{}`. My first question is: **What is the correct or proper way of doing this in these kind of lengthy equations?**

I also have another problem. When I use separate `\align` environments repeatedly, at some moment I reach to the end of the page and the last `\align` environment automatically starts from a new page. In such a case all vertical spaces of the previous page changes and they ruin the proper format of the text. So, my second question is: **How to properly arrange line breaks or spacing in repeated `\align` environments consisting lengthy equations?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `split` inside `equation` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\pi^{(1)}_{i j}
={}&  -\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\lambda \sigma} ( \eta^{\mu \alpha}\eta^{\nu \beta} + \eta^{\mu \beta}\eta^{\nu \alpha}  ) \biggl\{ \frac{1}{2}\delta_{\lambda 0}( \delta_{\mu i}\delta_{\nu j} + \delta_{\mu j}\delta_{\nu i}  )   \biggr\} \partial_{\sigma} h_{\alpha \beta}
\\
   & -\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\lambda \sigma} ( \eta^{\mu \alpha}\eta^{\nu \beta} + \eta^{\mu \beta}\eta^{\nu \alpha}  ) \biggl\{ \frac{1}{2}\delta_{\sigma 0}( \delta_{\alpha i}\delta_{\beta j} + \delta_{\alpha j}\delta_{\beta i} )  \biggr\} \partial_{\lambda} h_{\mu \nu}
\\
={}& -\frac{1}{4}\partial^{\lambda} h^{\mu \nu}\delta_{\lambda 0}( \delta_{\mu i}\delta_{\nu j} + \delta_{\mu j}\delta_{\nu i} ) -\frac{1}{4}\partial^{\sigma} h^{\alpha \beta}\delta_{\sigma 0}( \delta_{\alpha i}\delta_{\beta j} + \delta_{\alpha j}\delta_{\beta i} )
\\
={}& -\frac{1}{2}\partial^0 h^{i j} - \frac{1}{2}\partial^0 h^{i j}
\\
={}& \dot{h}_{i j}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The trick is to put `=` on the left side, following it with `{}` for ensuring correct spacing.

Avoid useless `\left` and `\right`. Also, no `\enspace` should be used around `=`.

[image]

The number should go in the middle, in my opinion. However, the `tbtags` option to `amsmath` will put it at the bottom of a `split`.

Comment: Your answer is very useful, thanks @egreg. I liked the idea of using `\split` and putting number into the middle and I will use them as the solution to my problem. But, the answer @Harish Kumar gave also works in my case. Since he additionally answers my second question I will accept his answer which I believe (and I hope) is ethically correct.

Comment: @sahin The additional question is a false problem: you should *never* have consecutive display environments. Use just one and add `\displaybreak` before the ``\\`` after which you'd like a break. Use `\allowdisplaybreaks` only when typing in the document, then decide by eye what are the best break points.

Comment: In my case, I used the `\allowdisplaybreaks` locally just before the `\align` environment that breaks the page and it worked. What are the possible bad consequences of using it like that? In any case, I again liked your suggestion. For a proper look, it could be better to use a single `\align` as you said. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeap! Now both of your solutions work for me and my document looks much better. I will change my decision on accepting answers. Thanks.

Comment: @egreg -- the minus signs that directly follow equal signs should really be unary minuses.  they show here as binaries.  granted, that would throw off the alignment of the initial fractions ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton The choice was exactly between preserving the alignment (with a slight violation of the “rules”) or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can add few `{}` and `\phatoms` to align.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    \pi^{(1)}_{i j} & = {}-\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\lambda \sigma} \left( \eta^{\mu \alpha}\eta^{\nu \beta} + \eta^{\mu \beta}\eta^{\nu \alpha}  \right) \biggl\{ \frac{1}{2}\delta_{\lambda 0}( \delta_{\mu i}\delta_{\nu j} + \delta_{\mu j}\delta_{\nu i}  )   \biggr\} \partial_{\sigma} h_{\alpha \beta}
    \nonumber
    \\
    &\phantom{{}={}}{}-\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\lambda \sigma} \left( \eta^{\mu \alpha}\eta^{\nu \beta} + \eta^{\mu \beta}\eta^{\nu \alpha}  \right) \biggl\{ \frac{1}{2}\delta_{\sigma 0}( \delta_{\alpha i}\delta_{\beta j} + \delta_{\alpha j}\delta_{\beta i} )  \biggr\} \partial_{\lambda} h_{\mu \nu}
    \nonumber
    \\
    & = {}-\frac{1}{4}\partial^{\lambda} h^{\mu \nu}\delta_{\lambda 0}( \delta_{\mu i}\delta_{\nu j} + \delta_{\mu j}\delta_{\nu i} ) -\frac{1}{4}\partial^{\sigma} h^{\alpha \beta}\delta_{\sigma 0}( \delta_{\alpha i}\delta_{\beta j} + \delta_{\alpha j}\delta_{\beta i} )
    \nonumber
    \\
    & ={} -\frac{1}{2}\partial^0 h^{i j} - \frac{1}{2}\partial^0 h^{i j}
    \nonumber
    \\
    & ={}\dot{h}_{i j}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

For your page breaking problem, use `\allowdisplaybreaks`.

[image]